# Conversion of Integer Arraylist to string

Tags: java, string, arraylist, integer, type-conversion

I'm trying to convert the numbers of my Array list into Strings at point i. How do I do this so I can create substrings of my numbers?

```
ArrayList<Integer> numbers= new ArrayList<Integer>();
for( int i=0; i<=10; i++){
    String numbersString[i] = String.valueOf(numbers[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `numbers[i]` is of type `Integer` you can just use its built in `toString()` method. However, as `numbers` is an `ArrayList`, you need to use `numbers.get(i)`.

`String numbersString[i] = ...` is invalid syntax. You have to declare your array outside the loop and then access it simply by `numbersString[i] = ...` inside the loop.

Comment: the question such as > what is it you are trying to accomplish? should be part of the comment rather then an answer

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like this.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (Integer number : numbers) {
  sb.append(number != null ? number.toString() : "");
}
System.out.println("The number string = " + sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking your code you need a input of ArrayList and output of String[].

You can use Collections2 of Guava lib to transform to string and after parse to array.

```
        ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        Collection<String> transform = Collections2.transform(numbers, new Function<Integer, String>() {

            @Override
            @Nullable
            public String apply(@Nullable Integer input) {
                return input.toString();
            }
        });

        final String[] array = transform.toArray(new String[transform.size()]);
```